# Question pine script when strategy exit contains stoploss, trailing stop, tp1, tp2

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[image]

I have 4 conditions to exit

1. stoploss : exit all positions
2. tp1 : exit position/3
3. tp2 : exit position/3
4. trailing stop : exit all positions

but not sure why trailing Stop exit only 200,  not 400 ?

```
strategy.exit("TP1", "Buy", limit=tp1, qty=strategy.position_size/3)
strategy.exit("TP2", "Buy", limit=tp2, qty=strategy.position_size/2)
strategy.exit("TrailingStop", "Buy", stop=tl, qty=strategy.position_size)
strategy.exit("StopLoss", "Buy", stop=stopLoss, qty=strategy.position_size)
```

[image]

I understand already today as

strategy.exit("TP1", "Buy", limit=tp1, qty=strategy.position_size/3) -> 600/3 contract : remain 400

strategy.exit("TP2", "Buy", limit=tp2, qty=strategy.position_size/2) -> 400/2 contract : remain 200

strategy.exit("TrailingStop", "Buy", stop=tl, qty=strategy.position_size) -> 200 contract : remain 0 : actually this one I would like to exit all as 400 contract

strategy.exit("StopLoss", "Buy", stop=stopLoss, qty=strategy.position_size) -> it will never match because contract already is 0 since Trailing Stop

So How to code it to meet my condition ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must exit TP2, with 100% of your balance
something like that:

```
strategy.exit("TP2", "Buy", limit=tp2, qty=strategy.position_size)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I might not explain clearly , now I understand the reason , but don't know how to code. example I entry with 600 contract

strategy.exit("TP1", "Buy", limit=tp1, qty=strategy.position_size/3) -> 600/3 contract : remain 400

strategy.exit("TP2", "Buy", limit=tp2, qty=strategy.position_size/2) -> 400/2 contract : remain 200

strategy.exit("TrailingStop", "Buy", stop=tl, qty=strategy.position_size) -> 200 contract : remain 0

strategy.exit("StopLoss", "Buy", stop=stopLoss, qty=strategy.position_size) -> it will never match because contract already is 0 since Trailing Stop